# Overlaying Images in MATLAB with different color channel

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have three binary images (generated with `zeros(height, width)`) created by MATLAB with R, G and B channel respectively. Now I want to overlap them together to form a color image.

What command can be used for generating the overlapped images with apply different channels together?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, an RGB image is saved as `m` by `n` by `3` array, where `m` and `n` are the height and width of the image. The image parts are thus:

```
rgbImage(:,:,1) = redImage;
rgbImage(:,:,2) = greenImage;
rgbImage(:,:,3) = blueImage;
```

Of course you should pre-allocate the image first to improve performance. A trick you can do for such arrays is to create it by

```
rgbImage(:,:,3) = blueImage;
rgbImage(:,:,2) = greenImage;
rgbImage(:,:,1) = redImage;
```

That way, a `m` by `n` by `3` array is allocated in the first step and the array doesn't have to be extended in the next steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to concatenate your single channel images into a multi-channel (colour) one:

```
rgbImage = cat(3, redImage, greenImage, blueImage);
```